# Rtsp server new client connected signal

Tags: c++, gstreamer, rtsp-server

I want to detect that which channel or factory is requested by client in new client handler `rtsp server in Gstreamer`. How can we detect factory or channel from these two argument `GstRTSPServer *server, GstRTSPClient *client in new_client_handler signal function`. `GstRTSPMediaFactory` is used for media-configure handler to register it’s signal handler.
this is my example code.

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771615/gstreamer-and-uri-query-parameters-extraction-for-each-new-client